# How to Route a call to the extension if No DTMF from user in XML IVR?

Tags: xml, scripting, ivr

I am writing the IVR in xml and after applying this code I've got that after playing main menu when I am pressing digit 3 and entering to the second menu (SPG_ivr_submenu) then if I do not press any digit it will replay the main menu again but I am trying that if I do not press any digit in second menu then call routs to extension 844. But using this code the main menu is repeated if user do not insert any DTMF in (SPG_ivr_submenu). Please tell me whats wrong with this code and what should I do to configure call routing exactly?

```
 <include>
     <!-- demo IVR setup -->
     <!-- demo IVR, Main Menu -->
     <menu name="demo_ivr"
        greet-long="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/coral.wav"
        greet-  short="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/coral.wav"
        invalid-sound="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/is_invalid.wav"
        exit-sound="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/ExitTone.wav"
        confirm-macro=""
        confirm-key=""
        tts-engine="flite"
        tts-voice="rms"
        confirm-attempts="1"
        timeout="10000"
        inter-digit-timeout="2000"
        max-failures="1"
        max-timeouts="1"
        digit-len="4">
        <!-- The following are the definitions for the digits the user dials -->
        <!-- Digit 1 transfer caller to the public FreeSWITCH conference -->
    <entry action="menu-sub" digits="3" param="SPG_ivr_submenu"/>
    <entry action="menu-sub" digits="2" param="support_ivr_submenu"/>
    <entry action="menu-sub" digits="1" param="corporate_ivr_submenu"/>
    <entry action="menu-sub" digits="4" param="delhiBranch_ivr_submenu"/>
    <entry action="menu-sub" digits="5" param="erp_ivr_submenu"/>
    <entry action="menu-top" digits="*"/>   <!-- Repeat this menu -->


  </menu>
```

```
          <!-- The demo IVR sub menu prompt basically just says, "press star to return to previous menu..." -->

       <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="set ringback=$${us-ring}"/>
       <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="bridge sofia/$${domain}/813@192.168.1.240"/>
       <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="2" param="set ringback=$${us-ring}"/>
       <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="2" param="bridge sofia/$${domain}/819@192.168.1.240"/>
       <entry action="menu-top" digits="*"/>
       <!-- <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits=xsi:nil="true" param="bridge sofia/$${domain}/844@192.168.1.240"/> -->

        </menu>
           <extension name="ext_SPG_ivr_submenu">
           <condition field="destination_number" expression="^844$">
           <action application="set" data="hangup_after_bridge=true"/>
           <action application="ivr" data="SPG_ivr_submenu"/>
           <action application="bridge" data="sofia/$${domain}/844@192.168.1.240"/>
    </condition>
 </extension>




</include>
```

Comment: What IVR platform is this? This is not standard VoiceXML.  The menu element for VoiceXML does not have all of the attributes you are showing and it uses the choice element instead of the entry element.  In VoiceXML you would be able to use the noinput element within the menu to handle the event where the caller did not provide any input.

Comment: Actually it is simple xml ivr scripting for freeswitch. You can see it at http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Dialplan_XML  .....